# Why is this first in-line block anchored at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, display, inline-styles

I have two blocks side by side: `#abc` and `#buttons` (the latter containing inline images).

I don't understand why the text "abcd" is floating on the bottom of the yellow div.

Question: **Why isn't it, by default, on top left of `#wrapper`?**

Side-remark: how to set this text "abcd" on top (vertically) or middle (vertically) of the yellow div?

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#abc, #buttons { display: inline-block; }
#wrapper { background-color: yellow; }
ul li { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="abc">
  abcd
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head why it's at the bottom (something about images causing a change here), but just use `vertical-align: top` if you want the text at the top. Out of close votes current but I'm sure this is answered by another question.

Comment: @TylerH it's not really the bottom but the baseline and the baseline of the image is its bottom so everything is aligned at their baseline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default if you set attribute into inline it will have `vertical-align` attribute as `baseline` it default behavior

but if you want to make it middle align or top you can change it into `middle`

see this code

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#abc, #buttons { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
#wrapper { background-color: yellow; }
ul li { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="abc">
  abcd
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can see [css trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/) for more detail

Comment: the default is baseline

Comment: yea you right i will update it

Comment: @TemaniAfif The code snippet (updated a few seconds ago) now works to align in the middle. Strangely, if *only* `#abc` is set to `vertical-align: middle`, then `#abc` still stays on bottom... Why? For it to work, it seems it is mandatory that both #abc *and* #buttons have `vertical-align: middle`. Why?

Comment: @Basj read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52634849/8620333